# How to configure phplist to use Gmail SMTP Server?

Tags: phplist

Anyone know how to configure phplist to use Gmail SMTP server?

Any advise? Thanks a lot for advice in advance

Answer (score 3):

Based on this page https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

I added the following to my config.php.

```
define("PHPMAILERHOST",'smtp.gmail.com');
$phpmailer_smtpuser = 'usernae@gmail.com';
$phpmailer_smtppassword = 'password';
define('PHPMAILERPORT','587');
define("PHPMAILER_SECURE",'tls');
```

No other changes were needed.
I did get a warning from Google that an attempt was made to access to my account and it was blocked.  I had to follow the steps to allow the connection.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Please help me on https://superuser.com/questions/1205929/not-able-to-send-mail-using-phplist about SMTP setting

Answer (score 1):

have look on it:

[Phplist and Gmail SMTP](http://forums.phplist.com/viewtopic.php?t=17376)